# Simulating a shell via socket connection - Python

Tags: python, linux, shell, sockets

**No, this is not part of a homework**

I'm working on a project where I need to simulate `shell` commands executed in a remote docker container. I'm able to obtain the connection to the container, which is an `OpenSSL` connection and a `socket`. 
When I execute commands like `command="ls"` then I'm able to read the output with `read()`:

```
def read(self, socket, n=4096):
    """
    Return `n` bytes of data from the Stream, or None at the end of the stream

    :param n:
    :return:
    """
    while True:
        try:
            if hasattr(socket, 'recv'):
                return socket.recv(n)
            return os.read(socket.fileno(), n)
        except Exception, e:
            print e
```

so for example:

```
container = self.client.create_container()
exec_id = self.client.exec_create(container, command, tty=True)
socket = self.client.exec_start(exec_id=exec_id, tty=True, stream=True)
response = self.read(socket)
```

I can get the following output:

```
bin       openssl
etc       share
include
lib       
license-eula.txt  var
```

However, things get more interesting when executing commands such as `/bin/bash`. So, in this case, I should keep the interacting with the connection, getting input from `stdin`, writing and reading from the socket...  I do have a way to resize the terminal, so that's not my biggest concern. My question is: How can I simulate a terminal via the socket connection? I do know about `dockerpty` but it won't work on my setup due to a `tls` connection ([Here's the ticket I created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709781/python-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version-error-in-docker-client-connection/39715026#39715026)).

Comment: Which part of the terminal do you want to simulate?

Comment: @E_net4 things like `/bash/bin` ... I want that to behave exactly like a shell.... I have done a lot of progress since last post ... maybe I should update my question?